# Android 11 "raw/:storage/..." file paths

Tags: samsung, file-system, android-11, documents

Hello Android community!

I am trying to recreate a way of putting a file on my emulator in a location, so that when picked it produces the following uri: **"raw/:storage/..."**

My challenge right now is I do not have a reproducible way of doing this. I have only gotten this raw uri once in my testing and can't anymore.

This is react native app, and we're using a forked version of image-crop-picker library.

Function: https://github.com/aarongrider/react-native-image-crop-picker/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/reactnative/ivpusic/imagepicker/PickerModule.java#L369

This is the function that returns the uri of the selected file: https://github.com/aarongrider/react-native-image-crop-picker/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/reactnative/ivpusic/imagepicker/PickerModule.java#L672

We're getting the following error from line 691 probably:
[image]

from calling the [resolvePath](https://github.com/aarongrider/react-native-image-crop-picker/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/reactnative/ivpusic/imagepicker/PickerModule.java#L546) which has a specific way of resolving the uri for Android API 19 and above: https://github.com/aarongrider/react-native-image-crop-picker/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/reactnative/ivpusic/imagepicker/PickerModule.java#L546

I am a complete newbie with Android, and just need a consistent way of producing the **raw/:storage/..** file uris. I appreciate any guidance provided here! Thanks :)

Comment: The only "raw" and "asset" things that I can think of are the `raw/` and `assets/` resource folders inside the APK though (refer to [App resources overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#ResourceTypes))

Comment: @AndrewT. Here is a link to the Github issue: https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll/issues/244#issue-714741338 - this is basically an issue on Android API level 30 (Android 11 ? Android Q ?) Here is a PR that aims to solves this https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll/pull/271